# cocoapods setup issue: inker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

I'm trying to setup cocoapods with a project in order to use the STPrivilegedTask class and have been running into the following error:

```
Ld ProductBuilder.app/Contents/MacOS/ProductBuilder normal x86_64
    cd /Users/zach/Dev/Code/ProductBuilder
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -L/Users/zach/Dev/Code/ProductBuilder -F/Users/zach/Dev/Code/ProductBuilder -filelist /Users/zach/Dev/Code/ProductBuilder/Build/Intermediates/ProductBuilder.build/Debug/ProductBuilder.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ProductBuilder.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -ObjC -lSTPrivilegedTask -framework Security -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/zach/Dev/Code/ProductBuilder/Build/Intermediates/ProductBuilder.build/Debug/ProductBuilder.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ProductBuilder_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/zach/Dev/Code/ProductBuilder/ProductBuilder.app/Contents/MacOS/ProductBuilder

ld: library not found for -lSTPrivilegedTask
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am able to use the STPrivilegedTask class in my code without any issues, it's just that I do not build - even without adding any STPrivilegedTask code, the app does not build.

Some other notes:

1. I am opening the project using the xcworkspace file.
2. STPrivilegedTask does show up in the Pods section in Xcode, and has it's source code there, so that seems OK.  As I said, I can also reference this class in code, so I think it's grabbing the class correctly.
3. The app I am adding cocoapods to is relatively old, but has not used cocoapods before, so this is a fresh install.
4. I am using cocoapods version 0.39.0

Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Thank you,
Zach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by changing my Per-configuration Build Products Path setting to:

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME).

I tested the STPrivilegedTask pod in a new project without any issues, so I figured it must be something with my project setup.  The project is somewhat of a legacy app, and has gone through some *odd* phases/cycles, so I can't explain why the Build Products Path was set to anything but that (the expected/normal value I think...)

Anyways, it builds OK now - hopefully this helps someone else!